# Make entire div area clickable hyperlink

Tags: html, css

How do I make the entire red area 'clickable'? I'd rather not use Javascript if I can help it.

https://jsfiddle.net/8m6z0h22/

```css
.block {
    width: 200px;
    height: 272px;
    background:red;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"> 
      <h3>Book a season ticket with Manchester United</h3>
      <ul> 
      <li><a href="#" title="Read more about Manchester United">Read more about Manchester United <span class="bold">></span></a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap all your code inside `<a>` tag instead of `<div>`.

```css
.block {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 272px;
    background:red;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
}
.block h3 {
  color: black;
}
.block ul li {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="Read more about Manchester United" class="block"> 
  <h3>Book a season ticket with Manchester United</h3>
  <ul> 
    <li>Read more about Manchester United <span class="bold">></span></li> 
  </ul>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Please search before asking questions.**

These links might help you

[How to make an entire div clickable with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354364/how-to-make-an-entire-div-clickable-with-css)

[How to make a whole 'div' clickable in html and css without javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160494/how-to-make-a-whole-div-clickable-in-html-and-css-without-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

you can add whole div in `a`

```css
.block {
    width: 200px;
    height: 272px;
    background:red;
    border: 0;
}
a{

    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="Read more about Manchester United"><div class="block"> 
      <h3>Book a season ticket with Manchester United</h3>
      <ul> 
      <li>Read more about Manchester United <span class="bold"></span></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the div inside the anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" title="Read more about Manchester United"><div class="block"> 
  <h3>Book a season ticket with Manchester United</h3>
  <ul> 
    <li>Read more about Manchester United <span class="bold">></span></li> 
  </ul>
 </div>
</a>
```