# How do you make a div a clickable link with HTML5/CSS3 only?

Tags: html, css, clickable

*T'is a question as old as time*, and as such the answers to the question are also as old as time.
I have tried many solutions, none of which have worked in the way I have wanted.

I am trying to make div .content1 wholly clickable link without any text or JS styling what-so-ever.
Do you have any suggestions?

```css
body {
  background-image: url("Images/background-bean.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
}

h1 {
  background-image: url("Images/background-bean.jpg");
}

p {
  background-color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 400px 400px 50px;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  background-image: url(Images/content/background_bean.jpg)
}

.nav {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  color: white;
}

.content1,
.content2,
.content3,
.content4 {
  background-color: #60330A;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.social {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  color: white;
}

.footer {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
}

.content1 {
  background-image: url(Images/content/c1standin.jpg)
}

.content1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.content2 {
  background-image: url(Images/content/c2standin.jpg)
}

.content2:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.content3 {
  background-image: url(Images/content/c3standin.jpg)
}

.content3:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.content4 {
  background-image: url(Images/content/c4standin.jpg)
}

.content4:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.a .content1:feature {
  position: relative;
}

.content1:feature a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* No underlines on the link */
  z-index: 10;
  /* Places the link above everything else in the div */
  background-color: #FFF;
  /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
  opacity: 0;
  /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
  filter: alpha(opacity=1);
  /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav"><span class="bold">NAV</span> </div>
  <div class="content1">
    <a title="Our Products" class="content1" id="header-img" href="Images/content/c1standin.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="content2">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="content3">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="content4">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="social">SOCIALMEDIA</div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h6>Image Credit pixabay.com; Elliott Evans 2019</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Define "clickable". What do you want to happen? When do you want this to happen?

Comment: "make div .content1 wholly clickable without any text styling whatsoever" clickable to doing what ? Enlarging the .content to full screen ? Can you use Javascript ? What are you trying to do with `:feature` ?

Comment: @el-teedee `:feature` is a feature `;-)`

Comment: @Martin Clickabke as a link to another page of the site. No JS. The :feature was something one of the websites I checked out told me to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17354432/912046 wrapping the `DIV` in a `A` is valid in HTML5. If it helps...

Comment: Only way to do it without Javascript would be to wrap the entire element in an anchor tag.

Comment: @el-teedee that does not work, it horribly mutilates the div. https://i.imgur.com/hR25bgG.jpg

Comment: it DOES work, you then have to update your CSS rules for the A to look like the old DIV

Answer (score 4):

You need to put anchor tag outside div.

```
<a title="Our Products" class="content1" id="header-img" href="Images/content/c1standin.jpg">
 <div class="content1"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still puts the text in a small box up the top (https://i.imgur.com/FaYOHeZ.png)

Comment: Sorry I am not able to see your image. Which text 'Our Products'?

Comment: It says "text" and it is at the very top

Comment: My guess is that it's because you've got the class "content1" on both the `<a>` and its child `<div>`. The little slice at the top is probably the `<div>`.

Comment: @ElliottEvans can you update the code snippet to reflect this change.

Comment: @showdev that worked, thank you! Just need to vert align the text and it will be perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As [answered by Rohit Shetty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54951880/924299), you can [wrap your `<div>` elements in `<a>` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320404/wrap-link-a-around-div), rather than the other way around. Also see [Make Entire Div Clickable](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/). Here's an example:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 400px 400px;
  grid-gap: 8px;
}

.content {
  background-color: #60330A;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform .3s;
}
.content:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.content1 {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?1')
}
.content2 {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?2')
}
.content3 {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?3')
}
.content4 {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?4')
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="content content1" title="Our Products" href="https://www.example.com">
    <div>OUR PRODUCTS</div>
  </a>
  <a class="content content2">CONTENT</a>
  <a class="content content3">CONTENT</a>
  <a class="content content4">CONTENT</a>
</div>
```

Alternatively (but probably unnecessarily), in order to make your `<a>` elements fill their parent `<div>` elements, you can set their size to `width:100%` and `height:100%`, like so:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 400px 400px;
  grid-gap: 8px;
}

.content {
  background-color: #60330A;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform .3s;
}
.content:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.content a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content1 {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?1')
}
.content2 {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?2')
}
.content3 {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?3')
}
.content4 {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?4')
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content content1">
    <a title="Our Products" href="https://www.example.com">OUR PRODUCTS</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content content2">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="content content3">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="content content4">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

However, unless you have a specific reason for an additional `<div>`, I suggest removing them and just using the `<a>` elements in your grid:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 400px 400px;
  grid-gap: 8px;
}

.content {
  background-color: #60330A;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform .3s;
}
.content:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.content1 {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?1')
}
.content2 {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?2')
}
.content3 {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?3')
}
.content4 {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?4')
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="content content1" title="Our Products" href="https://www.example.com">OUR PRODUCTS</a>
  <a class="content content2">CONTENT</a>
  <a class="content content3">CONTENT</a>
  <a class="content content4">CONTENT</a>
</div>
```